# Autoit MouseClick - click does not work on Connection Bar in RDP window

Tags: mouse, autoit, rdp

I am trying to minimize RDP window by using Autoit mouse functions
First MouseMove to correct location -> hint "Minimize" appear
but then MouseClick (or mousedown, sleep, mouseup) seems do click "through" connection bar , as I see icon on desktop under the connection bar got focused.

I thought before, any mouse action "by hand" can be imitated , but I am stuck here...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you need to do one of the following:

1. Run the program on the remote computer - then you can use the "standard" AutoIt functions
2. Run the program on the local computer, and analyze the remote image with ImageSearch UDF or OpenCV UDF and click in the selected point of screen.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that I am running scripts on remote PC, and whatever I run there seems active only on remote desktop. Script just don't see connection bar  that seems as kind of overlay on remote desktop. I tried to use Au3Info over connection bar, it does not even recognize it.

Comment: "connection bar" can you attach screenshot to your question ?